# iOS: How to implement a text field such that I can calculate typing speed, delete text

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview

I need to write a text editor for the iPad, and I need to be able to calculate the user's words per minute, and I also need to be able to delete the last few words -- while the user is typing. Any suggestions? Can I use UITextView for this? I had seen some people also have used HTML and contenteditable...

Any help is appreciated! I apologize in advance for the n00b question. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could user UITextView's delegate method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

And change the text property of the textView to delete the last few words. To calculate speed you could setup a NSTimer and divide the number of words in the text property by some length of time.